# Resize image inside polygon point path(svg) and make it not clipped

Tags: javascript, css, svg

I want to achive the following:

Resize the image inside the svg element to perfectly fit inside a polygon, and furthermore that it is fully viewable, and not clipped ( see jsfiddle).

I have gone through many stackoverflow questions but cannot figure it out:

Code:

```html
<svg width="50%" height="50%" viewBox="0 0 25 10"  preserveAspectRatio="none">
      <defs>
          <pattern id="im1" width="100%" height="100%" preserveAspectRatio="none">
              <image  preserveAspectRatio="none" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/abc" width="100%" height="100%"></image>
          </pattern>
      </defs>
       <polygon points="0,10 29, 10 10, 0" x="0" y="0" style="fill:url(#im1);"></polygon>
    
    </svg>
```

See `https://jsfiddle.net/f8ktzyLw/`

Can someone point me in the right direction ? is this achievable with svg only or do i need JavaScript/Canvas ?

Answer (score 1):

Polygon size 29px horizontal is 4px larger than viewBox = "0 0 25 10"

I added a gray frame that shows the boundaries of the SVG canvas

```html
<svg width="50%" height="50%" viewBox="0 0 25 10"  preserveAspectRatio="none" style="border:1px solid gray">
  <defs>
      <pattern id="im1" width="100%" height="100%" preserveAspectRatio="none">
          <image  preserveAspectRatio="none" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/abc" width="100%" height="100%"></image>
      </pattern>
  </defs>
   <polygon points="0,10 29, 10 10, 0" x="0" y="0" style="fill:url(#im1);"></polygon>

</svg>
```

To make the polygon fully fit inside the canvas of the SVG, it is necessary to increase the size of the SVG horizontally by 4px  `viewBox="0 0 29 10"`

```html
<svg width="50%" height="50%" viewBox="0 0 29 10"  preserveAspectRatio="none" style="border:1px solid gray">
  <defs>
      <pattern id="im1" width="100%" height="100%" preserveAspectRatio="none">
          <image  preserveAspectRatio="none" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/abc" width="100%" height="100%"></image>
      </pattern>
  </defs>
   <polygon points="0,10 29, 10 10, 0" x="0" y="0" style="fill:url(#im1);"></polygon>

</svg>
```

Or you can leave the dimensions of the `viewBox="0 0 25 10` unchanged, but then you need to reduce the horizontal size of the polygon by the same `4px`

```html
<svg width="50%" height="50%" viewBox="0 0 25 10"  preserveAspectRatio="none" style="border:1px solid gray">
  <defs>
      <pattern id="im1" width="100%" height="100%" preserveAspectRatio="none">
          <image  preserveAspectRatio="none" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/abc" width="100%" height="100%"></image>
      </pattern>
  </defs>
   <polygon points="0,10 25, 10 10, 0" x="0" y="0" style="fill:url(#im1);"></polygon>

</svg>
```